# How to add view matrix in modern Opengl

Tags: c++, opengl, matrix, vertex-shader, glm-math

**From The Start (kind of):** For months I have been using the fixed-function-pipeline, deprecated OpenGL functions like gluLookAt and glTranslate. After realizing I was doing so, I am now trying to correct my code starting with translations. I have an orange triangle that is working fine. When I implemented the model matrix I was able to move my triangle how I wanted (for the most part).
**To the point:** Now I am trying to create the view matrix and the projection matrix. I have not started the projection matrix yet. When I add the view matrix to my vertex shader, I cannot see my triangle anymore. I am really not sure why.
**My Vertex Shader:**

```
#version 150 core
in vec2 position;
uniform mat4 model;
uniform mat4 view;
void main()
{
    gl_Position=view*model*vec4(position, 0.0, 1.0);
}
```

**The Portion Of My C++ Code:**

```
glm::mat4 model=glm::mat4(1.f);
model=glm::translate(model,glm::vec3(0.5f,0.7f,0.f));
model=glm::scale(model,glm::vec3(1.f));
glUniformMatrix4fv(glGetUniformLocation(shaderProgram,"model"),1,GL_FALSE,glm::value_ptr(model));
glm::mat4 view=glm::lookAt(glm::vec3(-1,-1,-1),glm::vec3(0,0,0),glm::vec3(0,0,1));
glUniformMatrix4fv(glGetUniformLocation(shaderProgram,"view"),1,GL_FALSE,glm::value_ptr(view));
bool runOnce=true;
while(!glfwWindowShouldClose(window)){ //While glfw window is not closed yet
    glClearColor(0.1f,0.1f,0.1f,1.0f);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT|GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);//Clear buffers to preset values (Clears the screen each time)
    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES,0,3);//Draw array with _,_,x vertices
    if(runOnce){
      model=glm::rotate(model,glm::radians(1200.f),glm::vec3(0.f,0.f,1.f));
      view=glm::lookAt(
        glm::vec3(0.0f, 0.f, 0.f),
        glm::vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f),
        glm::vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f)
      );
    }
    runOnce=false;
    glUniformMatrix4fv(glGetUniformLocation(shaderProgram,"model"),1,GL_FALSE,glm::value_ptr(model));
    glUniformMatrix4fv(glGetUniformLocation(shaderProgram,"view"),1,GL_FALSE,glm::value_ptr(view));
    glfwSwapBuffers(window);//Swaps buffers (vertex data that is loaded to the screen by the gpu)
    glfwPollEvents();//glfwPollEvents, processes only those events (like keypresses) that have already been received and then returns immediately
}
```

If there is any more information I need to add, I would be happy to do so. Adding the projection matrix has not fixed the problem.
**My Entire C++ Code:**

```
//Load functions from usr/include/
#include <GL/glew.h>
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <glm/glm.hpp>
#include <glm/gtc/matrix_transform.hpp>
#include <glm/gtc/type_ptr.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
//Main function
int main() {
    std::ios_base::sync_with_stdio(false);//Disables the synchronization between the C and C++ standard streams (though  mixing C- and C++ style I/O will be a challenge)
    std::cin.tie(NULL);//Unties cin from cout for faster cin and cout functions (this does mean that they are off sync but if you are not using cin than it doesnt matter)
    if(!glfwInit()) {
        //Initialization failed
        fprintf(stderr,"Failed to initialize GLFW\n");//Initialization error
        return -1;//A -1 returned to the main function indicates a unsuccessful run
    }
    //Window hints change the way the window works (like settings)
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_SAMPLES,4);//4x antialiasing
    //"Major" and "minor" are two components of a single version number, separated by a dot.
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR,3);//Version 3...
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR,3);//.3
    //glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_FORWARD_COMPAT,GL_TRUE);//To make MacOS happy; should not be needed
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE,GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);//We don't want the old OpenGL
    const GLFWvidmode*mode=glfwGetVideoMode(glfwGetPrimaryMonitor());//Constant (not-changable) GLFWvideomode (variable type) is named "mode", is set to the primary monitor
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_RED_BITS,mode->redBits);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_GREEN_BITS,mode->greenBits);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_BLUE_BITS,mode->blueBits);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_REFRESH_RATE,mode->refreshRate);
    GLFWwindow*window=glfwCreateWindow(mode->width,mode->height,"My Title",glfwGetPrimaryMonitor(),NULL);//Create window that is the size of "mode" (constant primary monitor), named "", on the primary monitor
    if(window==NULL) { //If glfw window does not exist
        fprintf(stderr,"Failed to open GLFW window. If you have an Intel GPU, they are not 3.3 compatible.\n");
        glfwTerminate();//End glfw processes
        return -1;
    }
    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);//Initialize GLEW
    glewExperimental=true;//Needed in core profile
    if(glewInit()!=GLEW_OK) { //If glew is not okay
        fprintf(stderr,"Failed to initialize GLEW\n");
        return -1;
    }
    glViewport(0,0,mode->width,mode->height);
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    static const GLfloat g_vertex_buffer_data[]= { //Creates static (only runs once) constant (not-changable) array for VBO data
        -1.0f,-1.0f,0.0f, // triangle 1 : begin
        -1.0f,-1.0f, 0.0f,
        -1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, // triangle 1 : end
    };
    GLuint vao;//Declares variable vbo, GLuint (opengl's unsigned interger)
    glGenVertexArrays(1,&vao);
    glBindVertexArray(vao);
    //Upload this vertex data to the graphics card
    GLuint vbo;//Declares variable vbo, GLuint (opengl's unsigned interger)
    glGenBuffers(1,&vbo);//Generate 1 buffer
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,vbo);//To upload the actual data to the graphics card you first have to make it the active object
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,sizeof(g_vertex_buffer_data),g_vertex_buffer_data,GL_STATIC_DRAW);//Now that our VBO is active we can copy the vertex data to it
    const char*vertexSource=R"glsl(
    #version 150 core
    in vec2 position;
    uniform mat4 model;
    uniform mat4 view;
    unifrom mat4 project;
    void main()
    {
        gl_Position=project*view*model*vec4(position, 0.0, 1.0);
    }
  )glsl";
    GLuint vertexShader=glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER);//Creates shader object
    glShaderSource(vertexShader,1,&vertexSource,NULL);//Loads data to shader object
    glCompileShader(vertexShader);//Compiles shader object
    //Vertex compile error message
    int success;
    char infoLog[512];
    glGetShaderiv(vertexShader, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &success);
    if(!success)
    {
        glGetShaderInfoLog(vertexShader, 512, NULL, infoLog);
        std::cout << "ERROR::SHADER::VERTEX::COMPILATION_FAILED\n" << infoLog << std::endl;
    }
    const char* fragmentSource=R"glsl(
    #version 150 core

    out vec4 outColor;

    void main()
    {
      outColor = vec4(1.0, 0.5, 0.0, 1.0);
    }
  )glsl";
    //The fragment shader is compiled in exactly the same way
    GLuint fragmentShader=glCreateShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);
    glShaderSource(fragmentShader,1,&fragmentSource,NULL);
    glCompileShader(fragmentShader);
    //Fragment compile error message
    glGetShaderiv(fragmentShader, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &success);
    if(!success)
    {
        glGetShaderInfoLog(fragmentShader, 512, NULL, infoLog);
        std::cout << "ERROR::SHADER::FRAGMENT::COMPILATION_FAILED\n" << infoLog << std::endl;
    }
    //Combines shaders into one program
    GLuint shaderProgram=glCreateProgram();//Create shader program
    //Attatch vertex shader and fragment shader to new shader program
    glAttachShader(shaderProgram,vertexShader);
    glAttachShader(shaderProgram,fragmentShader);
    glLinkProgram(shaderProgram);//Links shader program
    //Shader program linking error message
    GLint linked;
    int InfoLogLength;
    glGetProgramiv(shaderProgram, GL_INFO_LOG_LENGTH, &InfoLogLength);
    if (InfoLogLength > 0) {
        std::vector<char> ProgramErrorMessage(InfoLogLength+1);
        glGetProgramInfoLog(shaderProgram, InfoLogLength, NULL, &ProgramErrorMessage[0]);
        printf("%s\n", &ProgramErrorMessage[0]);
    }
    //To actually start using the shaders in the program, you just have to call:
    glUseProgram(shaderProgram);
    //You first need to retrieve a reference to the position input in the vertex shader
    GLint posAttrib=glGetAttribLocation(shaderProgram,"position");
    glVertexAttribPointer(posAttrib,2,GL_FLOAT,GL_FALSE,0,0);//Specify how the data for that input is retrieved from the array
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(posAttrib);
    glm::mat4 model=glm::mat4(1.f);
    model=glm::translate(model,glm::vec3(0.5f,0.7f,0.f));
    model=glm::scale(model,glm::vec3(1.f));
    glUniformMatrix4fv(glGetUniformLocation(shaderProgram,"model"),1,GL_FALSE,glm::value_ptr(model));
    glm::mat4 view;//=glm::lookAt(glm::vec3(-1,-1,-1),glm::vec3(0,0,0),glm::vec3(0,0,1));
    glUniformMatrix4fv(glGetUniformLocation(shaderProgram,"view"),1,GL_FALSE,glm::value_ptr(view));
    glm::mat4 project = glm::ortho( -1.0f, 1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f, -1.0f, 10.0f );
    int prj_loc = glGetUniformLocation(shaderProgram,"project");
    glUniformMatrix4fv(prj_loc ,1,GL_FALSE,glm::value_ptr(project));
    bool runOnce=true;
    while(!glfwWindowShouldClose(window)){ //While glfw window is not closed yet
        glClearColor(0.1f,0.1f,0.1f,1.0f);
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT|GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);//Clear buffers to preset values (Clears the screen each time)
        glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES,0,3);//Draw array with _,_,x vertices
        if(runOnce){
          model=glm::rotate(model,glm::radians(1200.f),glm::vec3(0.f,0.f,1.f));
          view=glm::lookAt(
            glm::vec3(0.0f, 0.f, 0.f),
            glm::vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f),
            glm::vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f)
          );
        }
        runOnce=false;
        glUniformMatrix4fv(glGetUniformLocation(shaderProgram,"model"),1,GL_FALSE,glm::value_ptr(model));
        glUniformMatrix4fv(glGetUniformLocation(shaderProgram,"view"),1,GL_FALSE,glm::value_ptr(view));
        glfwSwapBuffers(window);//Swaps buffers (vertex data that is loaded to the screen by the gpu)
        glfwPollEvents();//glfwPollEvents, processes only those events (like keypresses) that have already been received and then returns immediately
    }
    glfwTerminate();
    return 0;//A 0 returned to the main function indicates a successful run
}
```

I am not sure that it will help but I am using xfce4 Crouton on a chromebook.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When I add the view matrix to my vertex shader, I cannot see my triangle anymore. I am really not sure why.

You don't use a projection matrix. This means that the clip space is equal the normalized device space. NDC is in range [-1, 1] (for x, y and z). All the geometry which is out of NDC is clipped.
This causes that your triangel is clipped by the far plane. Note, since you don't setup a projection matrix, the near and far plane are at -1 respectively at 1, because the normalized device space is in the range [-1, 1].

To fix your issue, add a projection matrix to the vertex shader:

```
#version 150 core

in vec2 position;

uniform mat4 model;
uniform mat4 view;
uniform mat4 project;

void main()
{
    gl_Position = project* view * model * vec4(position, 0.0, 1.0);
}
```

and set up an orthographic projection with an adapted far plane:

```
glm::mat4 project = glm::ortho( -1.0f, 1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f, -1.0f, 10.0f );

int prj_loc = glGetUniformLocation(shaderProgram, "project");
glUniformMatrix4fv(prj_loc, 1, GL_FALSE, glm::value_ptr(project));
```

Of course you can also use a perspective projection, somehow like this:

```
glm::mat4 project = glm::perspective( glm::radians(90.0f), 1.0f, 0.1f, 10.0f );
```

Further note, that the 2nd definition of the view matrix won't work, because the eye postion and the center position are equal. Change it to

```
if(runOnce){
    view=glm::lookAt(
        glm::vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f),
        glm::vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f),
        glm::vec3(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f)
     );
}
```

Note since your triangle is drawn in the xy plane, the eye position should have a z component, because if the line of sight would be in the xy plane, then the projection of the triangle would only be an infinitely thin line.

This means your program has to look somehow like this:

```
glm::mat4 model = glm::mat4(1.0f);
model = glm::translate(model,glm::vec3(0.5f,0.7f,0.f));
model = glm::scale(model,glm::vec3(1.f));

glUniformMatrix4fv(glGetUniformLocation(shaderProgram,"model"),1,GL_FALSE,glm::value_ptr(model));
glm::mat4 view = glm::lookAt(glm::vec3(-1,-1,-1),glm::vec3(0,0,0),glm::vec3(0,0,1));
glUniformMatrix4fv(glGetUniformLocation(shaderProgram,"view"),1,GL_FALSE,glm::value_ptr(view));

glm::mat4 project = glm::ortho( -1.0f, 1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f, -1.0f, 10.0f );
int prj_loc = glGetUniformLocation(shaderProgram,"project");
glUniformMatrix4fv(prj_loc,1,GL_FALSE,glm::value_ptr(project));

bool runOnce=true;
while(!glfwWindowShouldClose(window)){ 
    glClearColor(0.1f,0.1f,0.1f,1.0f);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT|GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES,0,3);

    if(runOnce){
      model=glm::rotate(model,glm::radians(1200.f),glm::vec3(0.f,0.f,1.f));
      view=glm::lookAt(
        glm::vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f),
        glm::vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f),
        glm::vec3(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f)
      );
    }
    runOnce=false;
    glUniformMatrix4fv(glGetUniformLocation(shaderProgram,"model"),1,GL_FALSE,glm::value_ptr(model));
    glUniformMatrix4fv(glGetUniformLocation(shaderProgram,"view"),1,GL_FALSE,glm::value_ptr(view));

    glfwSwapBuffers(window);
    glfwPollEvents();
}
```

There are a lot of further issues:

2 coordinates of your triangle are equal. Change it to

```
static const GLfloat g_vertex_buffer_data[]= {
    -1.0f, -1.0f,  0.0f,
     1.0f, -1.0f,  0.0f,
     0.0f,  1.0f,  0.0f,
};
```

Your vertex coordinates consits of 3 components, so it has to be:

```
glVertexAttribPointer(
    posAttrib,
    3, // <--------  3 instead of 2
    GL_FLOAT,GL_FALSE,0,0);
```

In the vertex shader there is a typo, it has to be `uniform` and not `unifrom`:

```
uniform mat4 project;
```